# Joins in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, join

I am a newbie to the `MySQL` database.I want to know different types of `joins` in `MySQL` and any link or any other kind of documentation with examples which will clear the doubts will highly appreciable.

Comment: You should ask a specific question. If you google for MySQL and join you get tons of explanations and examples.

Comment: Try going to Google and search for "MySQL join"...I believe that the official MySQL docs on JOIN syntax is the 2nd result that comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins are a concept of Relational Algebra, you can find [some information on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators).
Join is considered an [additional operator](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter3/node10.html#SECTION00123000000000000000).